# Failure near the start point

Tags: slicing, flashforge, flashforge-dreamer

The image below I indicated where the point where the tip of my extruder returns after changing the layer height, I don't know if I am right to call this point "Start Point" ...

[image]

The problem I am having is possible to see in the photo, because there is a slip of material and sometimes "webs" are created that compromise the quality of the print.

I tried to modify the retraction parameters, such as: speed and retraction length ...

Is there a parameter that I can modify to improve my print?

The slicer software I use is the : FlashPrint_4.5.1 (because I have a FlashForge Dreamer NX)

Comment: It seems to me that the photo is a little blurry and hard to see exactly what you're trying to demonstrate. Is the issue occurring in just the first (or early) layers or is it something you're seeing through all layers?

Comment: you have print outer walls frist on, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photo interpretation: I understand that the image on the right presents the actual error: it happens on many layers, following the red "Starting Point" line (so above it on the photo). Interesting issue. Btw. which side of the print is the bottom (zero layer)? - I believe the left side, and the right side is the top of the print.

The problem seems to apeear only in the middle of print. Top and bottom layers are usually printed slower, this could be some hint to find the reason. Also, I guess that the vertical cross section is not just a rectangle, but is wider on the top part? - then print parameters (e.g. speed) may change because of overhangs.

Could you share what type of filament do you print with? For example flexible materials will specifically react to the pressure and should not be forcefully retracted and pushed.
What type

Is there any exccessive material anywhere on the table? Like oozing or stringing? Do you see any material lost before printing the first layer? If not, the retraction is good enough or even too heavy - then try to minimize it: you may go down until you see any oozing, and then check the wall.

Could you share what range of parameters you have tried- especially the speed and retraction values? Jerk and accelleration? Do you use coasting or other pressure affecting techniques?

What is the hotend diameter? - the specs says 0.4 mm and the direct extruder. And (in comparision) what is the wall's line width for extrusion? What is the real width of this wall? (Is it properly sliced and reflected in G-Code? I advice to use G-Code viewer and inspect the details in given area.) What is the infill %, and how many wall lines do you have configured? And the layer height?

I hope this is of some help for diagnosis.

Comment: Hi welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! This answer is more a comment, it raises more questions for the OP for clarification of the problem, this is not what the answer section should be used for (we understand that the intentions are good), but that is where the comment section is for. When you reach up to 50 you will be able to comment and ask for more information.

Comment: Indeed, I could not ask in the comment :(  To add something constructive:  Recently I disabled "coasting" in Cura because I observed small gaps in printed lines, exactly were they were planned - visible on G-Code preview. My values for coasting was not very intensive, but apparently this phenomena did not occur, leaving gaps. Maybe because I print at low temperatures. I selected start randomly, and my view was not similar to the picture.

Comment: We all have to learn that SE is different from regular forums, many have been there, but your effort is appreciated! If you want to learn more, take the [tour] and look into [help]. You can also look into some highly voted answers to gauge the level that is expected. Hope to see you around!

Comment: Corrected by changing retraction parameter

Comment: That's fantastic! Did you increase or decrease? I am curious about the actual reason. If decreased, it could be extruder gears slipping.on filament. If increased, you should have noticed excess material somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently looked into "print outer walls first" in an attempt to make the seam vanish. But turning that setting on creates a webby structure on the following area for my printer.

Turning the setting off again (and reducing the outer wall speed to 30 mm/s) completely eliminated the ringing again.